# How to search and filter tweetts using Twitter API?

Tags: api, twitter, postman

I am exploring how to search and filter tweets using the Twitter API version 2 which as of this writing has been newly released. The documentation for this particular endpoint is available [here.](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/introduction)

I tried successfully searching for the following query:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=puppy
```

As I needed to be more specific, I checked out v1.1 docs [for rules and filtering](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rules-and-filtering/search-operators) and tried to look for tweets containing puppy images `(filter:image)` and no retweets `(-filter:retweets)` but I could not get the query in v2 (preferably) or v1.1 working with postman even though I tried [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for the special characters.

It is also not clear to me from the documentation (though mentioned in the docs) how to specify a certain `language` like English (`lang=english`) and a certain `distance` in the query `"37.781157,-122.398720,1mi"`

Does somebody know how to pass it into the query?

Answer (score 0):

For language filter you can refer the post

https://community.postman.com/t/define-the-language-of-tweets/20643

But I am not sure about the image filter. But in recent times a developer sean.keegan from Postman is talking more about twitter API's in Postman. Please do check out https://community.postman.com/search?q=twitter and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySbLo13Fk-c

I hope these will be helpful for you!!